# regex - add dot prefix excluding words that already have a dot

Tags: java, regex, processing

Lets say I have the following input strings:

```
range (bar | thumb_1 | thumb_2 | fill)
range(bar|thumb_1|thumb_2|fill)
.root.range.bar
```

Then I want the following output:

```
.range (.bar | .thumb_1 | .thumb_2 | .fill)
.range(.bar|.thumb_1|.thumb_2|.fill)
.root.range.bar
```

So far I have this:

```
void setup() {
  test("range (bar | thumb_1 | thumb_2 | fill)");
  test("range(bar|thumb_1|thumb_2|fill)");
  test(".root.range.bar");
}

void test(String in) {
  String r  = in.replaceAll("(\\w+)", "\\.$1"); // add . prefix to every word 
  println(r);
}
```

The problem is that if the word already has a dot prefix it will add another one.
I have been trying all kinds of things with `[^\\.]`.
But either it does not working on the last input string, or it starts eating wrong characters on the first and second input string.

How can I correctly ignore the cases where there is already a dot in front?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
.replaceAll("(?<!\\.)\\b\\w+", ".$0")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QWy6P2/1/).

**Details**

- `(?<!\\.)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `.` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `\\w+` - 1 or more word chars.

The replacement is a dot and the whole match value (`$0`).

See an [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/fuZP1D):

```
String s = "range (bar | thumb_1 | thumb_2 | fill)\nrange(bar|thumb_1|thumb_2|fill)\n.root.range.bar";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<!\\.)\\b\\w+", ".$0")); 
// => .range (.bar | .thumb_1 | .thumb_2 | .fill)
//    .range(.bar|.thumb_1|.thumb_2|.fill)
//    .root.range.bar
```

Answer (score -1):

You can first remove all the dots and then add them
like this (I've edited only `test(String in)` method):

```
void test(String in) {
    String r  = in.replaceAll(".","");
    r = r.replaceAll("(\\w+)", "\\.$1"); // add . prefix to every word 
    println(r);
}
```

Comment: This does not work.  A dot in a regex pattern matches any char but a line break char, and inside a replacement pattern, a dot is a literal symbol.